# trying to make an asterisk triangle in Swift using a while loop

Tags: swift, while-loop

I'm trying to make tan asterisk triangle output in Swift. I HAVE to use a while loop.

I have tried doing a while loop by it's self - no luck
I think I need to nest a while loop with a for loop but not even sure I can do that. Or I may be making this way harder than it needs to be :). Super new to programming...I simply do not know how to add an"*" in the while loop. below is the latest code that I have tried but it's wrong(obviously) any help would be appreciated

```
        let rows = 5
        for i in 1...rows{
            for j in 1...i{
                print("\(j) ", terminator: "")
            }
            var num_stars = 1


            while num_stars <= 5{
                print(num_stars)
                num_stars += 1

            }
              print("")

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `print("*")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply :

```
let rows = 5
var i = 1
while i <= rows {
    print(String(repeating: "*", count: i))
    i += 1
}
```

which outputs :

> ```
> *
> **
> ***
> ****
> *****
> ```

This looks prettier to me :

```
let rows = 5
var i = 0
while i < rows {
    let spaces = String(repeating: " ", count: rows - i - 1)
    let stars = String(repeating: "*", count: 2 * i + 1)
    print(spaces + stars)
    i += 1
}
```

> ```
>     *
>    ***
>   *****
>  *******
> *********
> ```

Or :

```
while i < rows {
    let spaces = String(repeating: " ", count: rows - i - 1)
    print(spaces, terminator: "")
    if i > 0 {
        print("*", terminator: "")
        if i < rows - 1 {
            let insideTriangleSpaces = String(repeating: " ", count: 2 * (i - 1) + 1)
            print(insideTriangleSpaces, terminator: "")
        } else {
            let insideTriangleStars = String(repeating: "*", count: 2 * (i - 1) + 1)
            print(insideTriangleStars, terminator: "")
        }
    }
    print("*")
    i += 1
}
```

> ```
>     *
>    * *
>   *   *
>  *     *
> *********
> ```

Comment: Why not a `for` loop?

Comment: @Alexander the OP said "*I HAVE to use a while loop.*"